Custom encoding of a struct
I'm trying to map the following SignUpRequest struct
struct SignUpRequest: Encodable {

    struct Customer: Encodable {
        let email: String?
        let firstname: String?
        let lastname: String?
        let privacy: Bool
        let privacy2: Bool
    }

    let customer: Customer
    let password: String?

}

in a JSON like this:
{
    "customer": {
        "email": "mike.m@yopmail.com",
        "firstname": "Mario",
        "lastname": "Rossi",
        "custom_attributes":[
            {
                "attribute_code":"consensopubb",
                "value":"3"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code":"consensopubb2",
                "value":"5"
            }
        ]
    },
    "password": "Password1!"
}

I tried to create a custom encoding of my struct.
struct SignUpRequest: Encodable {

    let customer: Customer
    let password: String?

    struct Customer: Encodable {

        let email: String?
        let firstname: String?
        let lastname: String?
        let privacy: Bool
        let privacy2: Bool

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case email
            case firstname
            case lastname
            case attributes = "custom_attributes"
        }

        enum AttributeCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case code = "attribute_code"
            case value
        }

        func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
            var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

            try container.encode(email, forKey: .email)
            try container.encode(firstname, forKey: .firstname)
            try container.encode(lastname, forKey: .lastname)

            // ...

        }

    }

}

My problem is that I can't figure how to encode privacy1 and privacy2 properties into JSON custom_attributes array.
-- EDIT --
privacy1 and privacy2 properties are Bool because map two checkbox that user can check or not. Unfortunately API wants an array of custom_attributes. consensopubb with value "3" if privacy1 is true. consensopubb2 with value "5" if privacy2 is true.

The custom encode(to:) should be done only in Customer, no? A quick way is to create a struct CustomAttributes: Encodable, and create it from values of privacy1 and privacy2, I guess you read theses values to create them?

How could you possibly convert a Bool to the values in the custom_attributes array? Why are you using Bool for those two properties? Or are they hardcoded values and the Bool only means if they should be included or not?

@JoakimDanielson I edited my question to answer your question.

A possible solution:
struct SignUpRequest: Encodable {
    let customer: Customer
    let password: String?
}

extension SignUpRequest {
    
    struct Customer: Encodable {
        let email: String?
        let firstname: String?
        let lastname: String?
        let privacy1: Bool
        let privacy2: Bool
        
        enum CustomerCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case email
            case firstname
            case lastname
            case attributes = "custom_attributes"
        }
        
        func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
            var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CustomerCodingKeys.self)
            var codes: [AttributeCode] = []
            if privacy1 {
                codes.append(AttributeCode(value: "3", code: "consensopubb"))
            }
            if privacy2 {
                codes.append(AttributeCode(value: "5", code: "consensopubb2"))
            }
            try container.encode(codes, forKey: .attributes)
            try container.encode(email, forKey: .email)
            try container.encode(firstname, forKey: .firstname)
            try container.encode(lastname, forKey: .lastname)
        }
    }
}
extension SignUpRequest.Customer {
    struct AttributeCode: Encodable {
        
        let value: String
        let code: String
        
        enum AttributeCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case code = "attribute_code"
            case value
        }
    }
}

Testing with:
let requests: [SignUpRequest] = [SignUpRequest(customer: .init(email: "email1", 
                                                               firstname: "f1",
                                                               lastname: "l1",
                                                               privacy1: true,
                                                               privacy2: true),
                                               password: "p1"),
                                 SignUpRequest(customer: .init(email: "email2", 
                                                               firstname: "f2",
                                                               lastname: "l2",
                                                               privacy1: false,
                                                               privacy2: true),
                                               password: "p2"),
                                 SignUpRequest(customer: .init(email: "email3", 
                                                               firstname: "f3",
                                                               lastname: "l3",
                                                               privacy1: true,
                                                               privacy2: false),
                                               password: "p3"),
                                 SignUpRequest(customer: .init(email: "email4", 
                                                               firstname: "f4",
                                                               lastname: "l4",
                                                               privacy1: false,
                                                               privacy2: false),
                                               password: "p4")]


requests.forEach { aRequest in
    do {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.outputFormatting = [.prettyPrinted, .sortedKeys] //For debug purposes
        let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(aRequest)
        let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
        print(jsonString)
    } catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
}

Now, I created a custom AttributeCode struct to make thing easier. Of course, you could customize all the encode and avoid that struct (which is pretty easy since it's a [String: String], but I feel that sometimes if the encode(to:) if too difficult for the user (for later debug, modifications), or the encode(to:) isn't clear enough at a quick glance, it a lot better to have explicit extra struct, you can make it private if needed and it can only be seen by SignUpRequest.Customer.
I made the custom encode on Customer, but indeed, it can be done with other modifications on SignUpRequest if only that one needs that special encoding and you don't want to modify the encoding of Customer (if it's not done through higher SignUpRequest), but with this should you have the whole idea.
Edit: If you don't really want AttributedCode struct, you can write:
var codes: [[String: String]] = []
if privacy1 {
    codes.append(["value": "3", "attribute_code": "consensopubb"])
}
if privacy2 {
    codes.append(["value": "5", "attribute_code": "consensopubb2"])
}
try container.encode(codes, forKey: .attributes)

It it was a [String: Any] it'd be more complex, and I'd still suggest to have the AttributedCode struct as it's easier to read at first glance, but both solution works and are valid.

Thank you Larme. But just out of interest, in your opinion, is there a way to achieve my goal without the use of the AttributeCode  support struct?

@Giorgio You can change the array variable to be a an array of dictionaries and then use hardcoded values in the append. var attributes = [[String: String]]()and then inside the if clause attributes.append(["attribute_code":"consensopubb", "value":"3"])

I stated in one penultimate paragraph that it's possible especially since the it's an "easy" [String: String] (it'd were a [String: Any] that would have been more complex.
